# Create user account with VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm using this code to create user account,

```
Function CreateUserAccount (acc, paas)

     Dim WinUserAccountName, WinUserAccountPass
    
     WinUserAccountName = Session.Property("WIN_USER_ACCOUNT")
     WinUserAccountPass = Session.Property("WIN_USER_PASS")
    
     strComputer = "."
     set objSystem = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
     set objUser = objSystem.Create("user", WinUserAccountName)
     objUser.SetPassword WinUserAccountPass
     objUser.SetInfo
    
End Function
```

It works OK so far, the only thing I need to implement is:

1. When the user name is already in the machine. Display message to the user telling him/her that this user name is already exist.

How can I do that in VBScript? Is there error code I can catch?

Thanks,

Comment: Which setup framework are you using?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the script I was looking for:

```
QueryForUser("kenmyer")
Wscript.Echo "This user account does not exist."

Sub QueryForUser(strUserName)
    strComputer = "."
    Set objDomain = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
    objDomain.Filter = Array("user")
    For Each User In objDomain
        If lcase(User.Name) = lcase(strUserName) Then
            WScript.Echo User.Name & " already exists."
            WScript.Quit
        End If    
    Next
End Sub
```